# Chaining multiple Promises, loop over array using map and create mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, promise

I'm retrieving a list of people from the database using `getPeople()`. As soon as I receive them as `res`, I want to prepare them to be stored in my local mongodb **if** they do not exist. Sometimes there're duplicate entries (for one `id`) within `res`. My issues is that it's not waiting for `Person.create(pers)` to finish, continues searching if this `id` is already in mongodb, can't find any since `Person.create(pers)` is still creating it and starts the second `Person.create(pers)`..

```
this.getPeople()
  .then(res => {
    return Promise.all(res.map(pers => {
      pers.birthday = df(pers.birthday, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
      pers.pickedUp = false
      console.log(pers.id)
      return Person
        .find({ id: pers.id })
        .exec()
        .then(found => {
          if (found === undefined || found.length == 0)
            return pers
        })
        .then(pers => {
          return Person
            .create(pers)
            .then(console.log('created'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
    }))
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I expected the console output to be like this:

```
940191
created
940191
created
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
940191
940191
created
created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Promise.all` simply awaits all the promises you're `mapping`. It does not guarantee any order in which the promises are resolved.

If you want to *sequentially* process the elements of your `res`-array, you can simply use a `for .. of` loop in combination with `async/await` (note that this still needs some error handling, but it should give you something to start with):

```
async function getPeopleAndCreateIfNotExisting() {
    const persons = [];
    const res = await this.getPeople();

    for (const pers of res) {    
        pers.birthday = df(pers.birthday, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
        pers.pickedUp = false;
        console.log(pers.id)
        const found = await Person
            .find({ id: pers.id }).exec();
        if (found) {
            persons.push(pers);
        } else {
            persons.push(await Person.create(pers));
        }
    }
    return person;
}
```

Comment: That helped, thanks. In the end I done it differently, but similar to your suggestion. :)

Comment: Great, happy to help! :)